# Asp.Net Identity Social Login - Open in fancy box

Tags: asp.net

Currently, I am working on ASP.Net Identity related project. I implemented code to use external login providers like Google, Facebook, Microsoft, Twitter and Yahoo in our project. It's working fine.

But, our client is asking us to open external provider login page in a fancybox and on clicking login button, the page need to be navigated to our actual project based on validation of login credentials. Please suggest me any solution.

Comment: So to clarify, clicking login needs to open the external provider login page as a FancyBox dialog. Once a user provides credentials, you want to redirect to your application?